# Any way to use the SFMC integrated Bitly link shortner within a Transactional SMS API JSON payload?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, rest, transactional-messaging-api

I created a Transactional SMS Send Definition via REST API (Transactional API), and am able to send SMS via API just fine.  Is there any way to shorten a dynamic link that is passed in to the API via an attribute?  Example: see below - you'll see an attribute called URL that is being passed in to the API call.  What I would like to do is shorten this URL.  We can do this via the UI using the typical, non-transactional way of sending SMS, but I can't figure out how to do this in real time using the Transactional API.

Edit: The end to end process looks like this:

1. Salesforce CRM makes an API call via an Apex class to SFMC's Transactional Messaging API.
2. SFMC receives the API call (JSON payload) and simply executes it (sending the SMS).

There's no AMPScript involved, although, a viable workaround would be for SFDC to make a POST call to a CloudPage instead, and have that CloudPage make the call out to shorten the URL via AMPScript, THEN, pass that into the Transactional Messaging API, but we are trying to keep this as out of the box as possible with no customizations (out of scope).

```
Host: https://YOUR_SUBDOMAIN.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
POST /messaging/v1/sms/messages/f4fe74b7-c3c0-4e5a-9f49-b63a641109a2
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN

{
  "definitionKey": "account-reset",
  "recipient": {
    "to": "15555551234",
    "contactKey": "Astro25",
    "attributes": {
      "URL": "https://www.asuperlongurl.com/"
    }
  },
  "subscriptions": {
    "resubscribe": true
  }
}
```

Comment: @LukasLunow it doesn't... I'm not using AMPScript, CloudPages, etc.  This is just a straight API call to the Transactional Messaging API, nothing intermediary.  I just need to see if there's a way to shorten a URL this way.

Comment: But you can use the Ampscript in the sms that you are sending???

Comment: Negative.  @LukasLunow The JSON will be passed by SFDC via an Apex class.  So completely agnostic of AMPScript.  The end to end looks like this.  1. SFDC makes API call to Transactional API in SFMC. 2. SFMC receives API call (JSON payload) and sends the SMS.

Comment: @LukasLunow Understanding that there are some viable workarounds here.  Like, example, have SFDC make a POST call to a CloudPage which contains the code needed to shorten the URL, then have the CloudPage execute the API call to send the SMS.  But, we are trying to keep this as out of the box as possible.

Comment: @LukasLunow actually you might be right... If I can use AMPScript in the Send Definition's message content, that could work.

Comment: That's my point. You must have the ability to adapt this URL string coming from the payload, as you for sure have the message defined, including a personalisation string which has the aim of printing your URL...